# Calling ILAsm vararg function from C#

Tags: c#, .net, clr, il

I am writing ILAsm function that receives variable number of arguments and returns their sum:

```
.class public auto ansi TestSentinel
{
    .method public static vararg unsigned int64 Sum( /* all arguments are optional */ )
    {
        .locals init( value class [mscorlib]System.ArgIterator Args, 
                      unsigned int64 Sum, 
                      int32 NumArgs )
        ... 
        ldloc Sum
        ret
    }
}
```

My dll compiles successfully but I cannot call this function from C# code. When I call it with

```
var k = TestSentinel.Sum(1);
```

I receive error message:

```
Error  The best overloaded method match for 'TestSentinel.Sum(__arglist, ...)' has some invalid arguments
```

And with any other number of arguments I receive `wrong argument number` message.
What is the correct way to call my ILAsm function?

Comment: Surprisingly, the .NET framework uses arglists: `public static void Console.Write(string format, object arg0, object arg1, object arg2, object arg3, __arglist)`. The C# compiler has undocumented syntax for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It requires using the undocumented __arglist keyword:

```
 var k = TestSentinel.Sum(__arglist(1));
 var l = TestSentinel.Sum(__arglist(1, 2, 3));
```

This isn't very useful, better focus on a params array instead.